# Why does this statment return true

Tags: perl

Why does this statement,

```
    if (! $ssh_options{user}) {

    delete $ssh_options{user};

}
```

return true, but this statement

```
    if ($ssh_options{user} eq 'undef') {

    delete $ssh_options{user};

}
```

give me the error,

```
Use of uninitialized value $ssh_options{"user"} in string eq at analyze.pl line 230.
```

I thought you always had to have something for perl to compare the value of the variable being compared.

** Update **

@ Quick Joe Smith

I cannot base my comparison on whether the hash keys exist or not because the values for this hash

```
sub ssh_connect {

my $host = shift;

my %ssh_options = (

    port => shift,
    user => shift,
    password => shift

    );
```

Come from this function which calls the sub routine

```
        if ((exists $config_file{user}) && (exists $config_file{password})) {

        my $vmware_user = $config_file{user};

        my $vmware_password = $config_file{password};

        ssh_connect($vmware_host, $vmware_port, $vmware_user, $vmware_password);

    } else {

        ssh_connect($vmware_host, $vmware_port);

    }
```

Comment: A good explenaition about `undef()` [http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html] und `exists()` [http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html] functsion exists in the perlfunc documentation. I assume `exists()` is what you are looking for in order to check the hash table for the key.

Comment: And for the record `($string eq 'undef')` is comparing the character bytes stored in $string to the five character bytes u-n-d-e-f, not an undefined value.

Comment: @Seth Robertson, OH! I did not know that. I thought I was actually comparing to undef.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl hash slots have a number of ways they can be false.  If the key has never been filled, the `exists` function will return false.  If the key exists but contains an undefined value, `exists` will be true but the `defined` function will return false. In normal boolean context, as given by an `if` statement, a hash key that was never filled, or is undefined,  `''`, `0` or anything that reduces to those will be false.

From your update, it sounds like what you want is to use `defined`

```
delete $ssh_options{user} unless defined $ssh_options{user};
```

Comment: Works great, nice one liner. Thanks.

Comment: You can remove the "anything that reduces to those" clause from your answer; there are exactly five false values in Perl: `undef`, the empty string, the empty list, the number zero, and the string "0" (but _not_ "00", "0E0", or any other way of writing the number zero as a string).

Comment: @Dave => by "anything that reduces to those" I meant things like overloaded and tied objects that return false values, but would be true to things like `ref`/`tied`, or string/arithmetic expressions that start from true values but yield a false value...

Answer (score 2):

Use `exists` for checking hash keys.

```
if (exists $ssh_options{user}) {
    ...
}
```

However, in your case, it seems as though you're checking for existing keys whose values may be undefined, in which case:

```
if (defined $ssh_options{user}) {
    ...
}
```

The above may be what you want.

---

As a sidenote, checking to see if the value of any variable is defined in the way you described:

```
if ($something eq 'undef') {
    ...
}
```

Is wrong. You're checking to see if the variable contains the string "undef". What you need in those situations is:

```
unless (defined $something) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think my answer has probably been updated as well. If not, how does it "not work"? I think my second code example is most applicable to your situation.

Comment: `if ($something == undef)` is also wrong.  That checks to see if `$something` equals 0 (the numeric value of `undef`).  The correct test is `if (!defined $something)`.

Comment: @ Quick Joe Smith, I just saw your update. I was referring to your original post.

Comment: @ cjm, Can `$something` be `$hash{key}`?

Comment: @Quick Joe Smith, No, definitely wrong. `== undef` doesn't check if the LHS is undefined, it checks if its zero.

Answer (score 1):

But if `$ssh_options{"user"}` is uninitialized then it it doesn't have a value to compare to.

Comment: So if you are not comparing to another value, what are you doing then? Comparing the value to uninitialized?

Comment: Your code is trying to compare the value to the string `'undef'`.  If `$ssh_options{"user"}` is unitialised it can't be compared to a string, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

With Perl, undefined evaluates to false in Boolean context.  So your first test 'works' as you expect.  However, it might introduce a bug if zero or an empty string is a legitimate value for `$ssh_options{user}` to hold, if you don't wish to treat that the same as undef.  That's because your first test doesn't differentiate between false as a value, and false as undefined.  As far as Perl's Boolean evaluation goes, all of the following are "false": `0`, `''` (empty string), `undef`, or an empty list.

Your second snippet of code fails because `undef` should be a bareword, not a quoted string.  'undef' as a quoted string IS a value, which would actually evaluate to 'true' in Boolean tests.  Because you're comparing an actual value to your hash element, Perl warns you that you're comparing something to an undefined value.  In this case, the undefined value is `$ssh_options{user}`.  It's actually good that Perl is warning you; it's given you a clue as to what you're doing wrong.

If you really want to test whether $ssh_options{user} is defined, use the defined() function.  If you want to test whether $ssh_options{user} exists, use the exists() function.

Comment: +1, if only because I have no idea why this perfectly-good answer might have been downvoted.